# Convert Octave Function to Java

Tags: java, octave

I'm trying to convert some Octave functions to Java, but I'm not sure I'm this right.

```
function [y,a] = forwardProp(x, Thetas)
    a{1} = x;
    L = length(Thetas)+1;
        for i = 2:L,
            a{i-1} =[1; a{i-1}];
            z{i} =Thetas{i-1}*a{i-1};
            a{i} =sigmoid(z{i});
        end 
    y = a{L};
end
```

My Java Function

```
public class ForwardProp {

public static DoubleMatrix ForwardProp(DoubleMatrix x, DoubleMatrix Thetas) 
{
    DoubleMatrix a = new DoubleMatrix();
    a = DoubleMatrix.concatHorizontally(DoubleMatrix.ones(a.rows, 1), x);

    int L = Thetas.length + 1;

    DoubleMatrix z = new DoubleMatrix();

    for (int i = 2; i <= L; i++) 
    {
        a.put(i - 1, a.get(i - 1));
        z.put(i, (Thetas.get(-1) * a.get(i - 1)));
        a.put(i, Sigmoid(z.get(i)));
    }
    return a;
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me if this is right???

Comment: Does it work for your data? If so, it is right, if not it's wrong, having us do QA for you is not what SO is for.

Comment: Have you tried testing it? What do you pass to octave and get back? Are you passing the same thing and getting the same result back?

Comment: Sorry I know that, it doesn´t work with my data.. I'm having troubles converting my loop arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you are committing a double-fencepost error here:

`int L = Thetas.length + 1;`

`L` now equals 1 more than the number of elements in the matrix...

`for (int i = 2; i <= L; i++)` ...and you are now looping with `Thetas.get(i - 1)` all the way up to an index that is 2 greater than the highest index available from `Thetas.get(int)`.

Remember, `Thetas.get(int)` directly accesses the internal array that stores this matrix's data. This can only accept indices from 0 to `Thetas.length - 1`. So when you call `Thetas.get(-1)` you will always get an error because -1 is not a valid array index; when you get to the end of the loop and call `Thetas.get(i - 1)`, you will get an error again because there is no element at that location.

You are also initializing your output matrix with `DoubleMatrix z = new DoubleMatrix();`, which returns a 0x0 empty matrix with no elements. That's not what you want either.

Try to make sure you know which indices your data is in, then rewrite it when you know how to reference the data you are using.

Comment: Thanks @Widdershins for your help. I'm trying to make some changes in my code, the problem is that I'm new in java but I've to make a neural network for college... nice way to learn java =)